# SPF record definition within Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, gmail, google-workspace

I've got an application that is hosted on aws, but mail is sent via google. I'm using Route 53 for my DNS. I'm trying to figure out what to use for an SPF record within Route 53 to enhance the deliverability of my emails.

Within the SPF record, I understand that I need to specify the mail server in either domain, ip4, or ip6 format.

Within the SPF record, would I use the ip address of my load balancer on aws or would I specify my domain name? Alternatively, should I indicate a domain name or IP address that represents GSUITE's servers?

I'm very confused. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow [this guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en) which gives you the SPF record to use for your Google email service. Since your load balancer and AWS servers are not involved in your email service, they would not be included in the SPF record.